# Kotlin from xml to html with style

Tags: java, android, html, xml, kotlin

i have an xml file with some style :

```
<section><text><bold><italic>Iris Mittenaere </italic></bold>Son nouveau mec est une bombe !</text><text><bold><italic>Harry &amp; Meghan </italic></bold>Ils quittent l'Angleterre à cause de William !</text><text><bold>INTERVIEW EXCLUSIVE </bold>L'émission de TF1 truquée ? Un danseur balance</text><text><bold>SCOOP <italic>Camille Combal </italic></bold>Et maintenant le bébé ! Deux mois à peine après son mariage, l'animateur star de TF1 est prêt à agrandir la famille avec Marie !</text><text><bold><italic>Jenifer </italic></bold>Visée par un incendie criminel!</text></section>
```

I use dom as sugested here : https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-xml-to-html , to get the header and everything before the section and convert it to html, it s work fine. My probleme is that i can only get tag one by one, it s work perfect of the header but here i got multiple tag text so i only get the first one.

With jaksonxml found here : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization , i managed to get multiple line for text but i can't get the style meaning i can't reteive `<bold><italic>` tag.

Does anyone know how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to deal with it, i think it's not clean but i couldn't come up with anything better. What i did is that i replaced xml tag with html tag :

```
text = text.replace("<article>","<body><article>")
        text = text.replace("bold", "b")
        text = text.replace("italic", "i")
        text = text.replace("text", "p")
```